# Proving lower bound of Integer Linear Program (ILP)

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Consider an Integer Linear Program (ILP) of the following form:

**ILP 1:**
Minimize $c^1x^1 + c^2 x^2+ c^3 x^3$

Subject to:

\begin{align}
A^1x^1 &\leq b^1\\
A^2x^2 &\leq b^2\\
A^3_1x^1 + A^3_2x^2 + A^3_3x^3 &\leq b^3\\
x^1, x^2, x^3 \geq 0\\
x^1, x^2, x^3 \;\text{are integer vectors}
\end{align}

We have the following relaxations.

**LP ($p$):**
Minimize $c^1x^1 + c^2 x^2+ c^3 x^3$

Subject to:

\begin{align}
A^1x^1 &\leq b^1\\
A^3_1x^1 + A^3_2x^2 + A^3_3x^3 &\leq b^3\\
x^1, x^2, x^3 \geq 0
\end{align}

Solving LP $p$ gives integral solutions $x^1_p, x^2_p=0, x^3_p$.

**LP ($q$):**
Minimize $ c^2 x^2+ c^3 x^3$

Subject to:

\begin{align}
A^2x^2 &\leq b^2\\
A^3_2x^2 + A^3_3x^3 &\leq b^3\\
x^1, x^2, x^3 \geq 0
\end{align}

Solving LP $q$ gives a solution $x^2_q, x^3_q$, not necessarily integral.

**LP ($r$):**
Minimize $c^1x^1 +c^2x^2+ c^3 x^3$

Subject to:

\begin{align}
A^1x^1 &\leq b^1\\
A^3_1x^1 + A^3_2(x^2_q+x^2) + A^3_3(x^3_q+x^3) &\leq b^3\\
x^1, x^2, x^3 \geq 0
\end{align}

Solving LP $r$ gives integral solutions $x^1_r=x^1_p, x^2_r=0, x^3_r=x^3_p$.

Then is $c^1x^1_p+c^3x^3_p+c^2x^2_q+c^3x^3_q$ lower bound for the ILP? It seems intuitive to me because of the result in LP $r$, but I am not able to give a formal proof. If it is not a lower bound then is there a simple condition under which this will be true?

**Additional Information:**
The key aspect of the problem is the condition from LP $r$. This property is proved using duality. Of course, if we don't consider the condition, the value of $c^1x^1_p+c^3x^3_p+c^2x^2_q+c^3x^3_q$ is not a lower bound as shown in one of the answers by @prubin.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Fixed. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I have fixed the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sum is not a lower bound. Here is a counterexample, in which all variables are scalar:
\begin{align*}
\min\quad & x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}\\
\textrm{s.t.}\quad & x_{1}\le5\\
 & x_{2}\le5\\
 & x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3}\le-6\\
 & x\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}^{3}.
\end{align*}
By inspection, the optimal solution is $(0,0,3)$ with objective value 3. Your first LP is
\begin{align*}
\min\quad & x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}\\
\textrm{s.t.}\quad & x_{1}\le5\\
 & x_{1}+x_{2}-2x_{3}\le-6\\
 & x\ge 0
\end{align*}with optimal solution $(0,0,3)$ and objective value 3. Your second LP is
\begin{align*}
\min\quad & x_{2}+x_{3}\\
\textrm{s.t.}\quad & x_{2}\le5\\
 & x_{2}-2x_{3}\le-6\\
 & x\ge 0
\end{align*}with optimal solution $(x_2,x_3)=(0,3)$ and optimal value 3. Add the objective values together and you get 6, which is not a lower bound for the value (3) of the ILP.

As to conditions under which you would get a valid lower bound, I have no suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you are correct if one considers only the first two LPs ($p$ and $q$). However, your intuitive example doesn't comply with the result from LP $r$. In this case, the optimal solution is $(0, 0, 0)$ for LP $r$, which is not the same as the solution from LP $p$.

Comment: So an assumption of what you are doing is that LP $r$ and LP $p$ will have the same solution? I took that just be an outcome of your example, rather than an assumption/restriction.

Comment: Yes, that is the assumption, and the main property of the problem. It is not specific to an example.

Comment: I was able to prove this property using duality. Currently, I am looking into Lagrangian duality and Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition to get some insight into proving the result.